# How can I add types to use Intl.ListFormat in node v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am using nodeJS v12.10.0
This supports `Intl.ListFormat`
Using Typescript v3.6.3

However, when compiling with typescript, I get *Property 'ListFormat' does not exist on type 'typeof Intl' (ts2339)* error.

I've tried googling and found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29129) and other advice, but nothing has worked.

A consensus of what I've found seems to be to use a `name.d.ts` file and to somehow extend the `Intl` object there, but I haven't been able to.

I am still learning typescript, but am familiar with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following in a `something.d.ts` file seems to work.

```
declare namespace Intl {
  class ListFormat {
    public format: (items: [string?]) => string;
  }
}
```

I got the idea from my original googling, but then reading [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) helped me work it out.

Posting this in case it helps others.

Answer (score 5):

I found that the accepted answer didn't work for me. I used the following:

```
declare namespace Intl {
  class ListFormat {
    constructor(locales?: string | string[], options?: Intl.ListFormatOptions);
    public format: (items: string[]) => string;
  }
}
```